# Is it possible to set the current Linux runlevel programmatically?

Tags: c, linux, runlevel

Without shelling out or calling exec, is there a way to request a runlevel change programmatically?

Comment: Which init-system do you use?

Comment: sys-v - embedded

Comment: `Without shelling out or calling exec` - how do you change runlevel on your system when calling the shell or when calling exec? - inspect the source code of that entity you call - extract the "programmaticall" way of changing it. How does "programaticall change" differs from "shelling out" or "calling exec"?

Comment: So I don't want to call "system (telinit 4)" for example. However I equally don't want to dip into the source for init and do what it does, that's not a stable API. So I was wondering if there was a stable API to sys-v init. systemd, I'm guessing, uses DBus.

Answer (score 2):

Sys-V init opens a fifo at /run/initctl . The command you can send is "described" in initreq.h (most probably not installed on your system but can be found in the sources of init).

So all you have to do is to open /run/initctl and write the request into it.

```
struct init_request request= {.magic = INIT_MAGIC, 
                              .cmd = INIT_CMD_START, 
                              .runlevel= [your_run_level], 
                              .sleeptime = 5  //should sleep 5s between term and kill
                             };
```

Comment: Yes, but:
`.cmd = INIT_CMD_RUNLVL`
and, for runlevel 6:
`.runlevel = '6'`